# AutoHotkey in ssms query windows

Tags: autohotkey, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to get information from individual query windows in SQL Server Management Studio 2008? I've found a lot of information online about MDI windows in general, but most of it, according to my experiments, just doesn't work in ssms. The best solution I've found looks like this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
DetectHiddenWindows On
w =
WinGet id, list, sql
;WinGet id, list, ahk_class VBBubble
Loop %id%
{
    WinGetTitle t, % "ahk_id " id%A_Index%
    w .= "`n" t
}
MsgBox %w%
DetectHiddenWindows Off
```

This consistently returns the title of one of the query windows I have open; I assume I could get other information about the window using that ahk_id. The problem is that it only ever returns one result, regardless of how many queries are open. If it was consistently the top one, that would even be fine; in fact, it would actually be perfect for my purposes. However, it seems to find one query window at random, without regard to the actual order or anything that I have found.

This is weird and annoying. Any help with it would be appreciated.

Rob

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the windows by their class, rather than by their title? Alternatively, you could try ahk_exe. You can analyze a window using window spy.

Comment: What is your goal ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @AndreiRantsevich At the moment, I'm trying to re-purpose the Escape key to cancel a running query without removing its existing functionality. Ideally, it would only act differently when the top query window is currently executing a query. If I could consistently get information about the top query window, I have no doubt I'd find other things I could do with that.

Comment: @MCL I have now. The class appears to be "VBBubble," but replacing the WinGet command above by `WinGet id, list, ahk_class VBBubble` does not change the result. The process name appears as Ssms.exe, and using `WinGet id, list, ahk_exe Ssms.exe` returns 196 results, of which 188 are empty strings. The other eight consist in the main ssms window; a few things I recognize as sub-components ("Object Explorer"); and several that I don't recognize ("M", "GDI+ Window"); but nothing that resembles what I'm looking for. Window Spy only seems to want to tell me about the parent window.

Comment: My opinion is that you need to write an add-in to achieve what you want. I develop an ssms-addin myself (see my profile info), and can only tell you that it is rather complicated task. There are several add-in samples for ssms 2008 and 2012 that you can find and re-use. Some of them are present on codeplex.

Comment: @AndreiRantsevich I was actually unaware that ssms supported add-ins, but I have been able to write a small add-in that changes the functionality of the escape key, and so far it seems to have no side effects. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: -- Try using AutoHotkey's AccViewer on the query windows to find out more information about them. -- Possibly the windows are not separate windows but are within the main window. -- Possibly the windows are controls within the main window, retrievable via `WinGet, vCtlList, ControlList, ahk_id %hWnd%`. -- Possibly you can retrieve information via COM (Component Object Model) in AutoHotkey,